# Drawing multiple rectangles inside linear layout

Tags: android, shapes

I'm trying to draw multiple rectangles inside of a linear layout which is sitting inside of a scrollview. This is my code for the rectangle view:

```
private class RectView extends View{

    int leftX, rightX, topY, bottomY;
    boolean isAppt;
    private Paint rectPaint;
    private Rect rectangle;

    public RectView(Context context, int _leftX, int _rightX, int _topY, int _bottomY, boolean _isAppt){
        super(context);
        leftX = _leftX;
        rightX = _rightX;
        topY = _topY;
        bottomY = _bottomY;
        isAppt = _isAppt;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){

            rectPaint = new Paint();

        if(isAppt){
            rectPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 255);
            rectPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else{
            rectPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
            rectPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        rectPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        rectPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        rectangle = new Rect(leftX, topY, rightX, bottomY);

    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, rectPaint);
    }

}
```

And this is how I'm currently trying to display the rectangles:

```
RectView rv = new RectView(context, 0, 100, 0, 100, true);
firstDemarc.addView(rv);
firstDemarc.postInvalidate();
```

firstDemarc is the linear layout inside of my scrollview. Currently I'm not seeing any rectangles. The onDraw function is not being called. How do I properly display the rectangles inside of my scrollview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the view some layout parameters:

```
int width = right - left;
int height = bottom - top;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
params.leftMargin = left;
params.topMargin = top;
setLayoutParams(params);
```

When you draw the rect, you need to draw from 0,0, until the width / height of the rect. The linear layout will handle the positioning according to the margins / layout params.